# Getting Bluetooth to work in Arch Linux

Tags: linux, bluetooth, arch-linux

I recently installed BBQLinux on USB flash drive. The wireless is working fine, but I can't figure out how to get bluetooth to work to connect my keyboard. Here is the list of modules loaded:

```
mmc_block              34914  0 
cdc_acm                30362  0 
fuse                   87590  3 
ctr                    12927  3 
ccm                    17534  3 
rtsx_usb_ms            16899  0 
memstick               13696  1 rtsx_usb_ms
nls_iso8859_1          12461  1 
nls_cp437              16553  1 
vfat                   21231  1 
fat                    62032  1 vfat
ecb                    12737  1 
iTCO_wdt               12831  0 
coretemp               12820  0 
ath3k                  12685  0 
hwmon                  12930  1 coretemp
intel_rapl             17605  0 
iTCO_vendor_support    12649  1 iTCO_wdt
btusb                  30036  0 
intel_powerclamp       17122  0 
bluetooth             433830  3 ath3k,btusb
joydev                 17063  0 
mousedev               17272  0 
kvm_intel             143417  0 
arc4                   12536  2 
kvm                   435299  1 kvm_intel
r8169                  76869  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49263  1 
crct10dif_pclmul       13394  0 
ath9k                 129093  0 
crc32_pclmul           12915  0 
crc32c_intel           21809  0 
ath9k_common           26722  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              428874  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ghash_clmulni_intel    12978  0 
cryptd                 18553  1 ghash_clmulni_intel
ath                    26067  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
evdev                  21544  13 
mac_hid                12633  0 
mac80211              648753  1 ath9k
pcspkr                 12595  0 
psmouse               107442  0 
serio_raw              12849  0 
mii                    12675  1 r8169
snd_hda_codec_realtek    67322  1 
cfg80211              476584  4 ath,ath9k_common,ath9k,mac80211
snd_hda_codec_generic    63087  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
i2c_i801               16965  0 
i915                 1002472  2 
rfkill_gpio            12531  0 
toshiba_bluetooth      12641  0 
snd_hda_intel          26387  3 
snd_hda_controller     26857  1 snd_hda_intel
toshiba_acpi           27156  0 
sparse_keymap          12818  1 toshiba_acpi
thermal                17559  0 
ac                     12715  0 
fan                    12726  0 
battery                17452  0 
dw_dmac                12610  0 
dw_dmac_core           21699  1 dw_dmac
spi_pxa2xx_platform    22562  0 
rfkill                 18867  5 cfg80211,toshiba_acpi,bluetooth,rfkill_gpio
8250_dw                13067  0 
snd_hda_codec         112621  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_hwdep              17244  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                88779  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_timer              26614  1 snd_pcm
wmi                    17339  1 toshiba_acpi
video                  22205  1 i915
drm_kms_helper         98881  1 i915
i2c_hid                17403  0 
intel_gtt              17848  1 i915
snd                    73436  14 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
i2c_designware_platform    12645  0 
i2c_designware_core    12813  1 i2c_designware_platform
button                 12953  1 i915
iosf_mbi               12682  1 intel_rapl
i2c_algo_bit           12744  1 i915
shpchp                 35210  0 
mei_txe                18098  0 
mei                    75468  1 mei_txe
lpc_ich                20768  0 
soundcore              13031  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
processor              27777  0 
sch_fq_codel           17343  6 
vboxvideo              12437  0 
drm                   273125  5 i915,drm_kms_helper,vboxvideo
i2c_core               50240  7 drm,i915,i2c_i801,i2c_hid,i2c_designware_platform,drm_kms_helper,i2c_algo_bit
nfs                   208487  0 
lockd                  87230  1 nfs
grace                  12586  1 lockd
sunrpc                275966  2 nfs,lockd
fscache                53701  1 nfs
ext4                  514390  1 
crc16                  12343  2 ext4,bluetooth
mbcache                17171  1 ext4
jbd2                   86379  1 ext4
rtsx_usb_sdmmc         25280  0 
rtsx_usb               17487  2 rtsx_usb_sdmmc,rtsx_usb_ms
uas                    21817  0 
usb_storage            60311  3 uas
hid_generic            12393  0 
usbhid                 48596  0 
hid                   110513  4 i2c_hid,hid_generic,usbhid
sr_mod                 21903  0 
cdrom                  47479  1 sr_mod
sd_mod                 43575  3 
atkbd                  22254  0 
libps2                 12739  2 atkbd,psmouse
xhci_pci               12675  0 
xhci_hcd              152471  1 xhci_pci
ahci                   33248  0 
libahci                27215  1 ahci
usbcore               199382  9 uas,ath3k,btusb,rtsx_usb,usb_storage,usbhid,cdc_acm,xhci_hcd,xhci_pci
libata                181461  2 ahci,libahci
usb_common             12561  1 usbcore
scsi_mod              147395  5 uas,usb_storage,libata,sd_mod,sr_mod
i8042                  18002  2 toshiba_acpi,libps2
serio                  18282  6 serio_raw,atkbd,i8042,psmouse
sdhci_acpi             12961  0 
sdhci                  39102  1 sdhci_acpi
led_class              12855  4 ath9k,toshiba_acpi,sdhci,rtsx_usb_sdmmc
mmc_core              110613  4 mmc_block,sdhci,sdhci_acpi,rtsx_usb_sdmmc
```

I noticed there are couple bluetooth modules loaded:

```
   bluetooth             433830  3 ath3k,btusb 
   toshiba_bluetooth      12641  0 
   rfkill                 18867  5 cfg80211,toshiba_acpi,bluetooth,rfkill_gpio
   crc16                  12343  2 ext4,bluetooth
```

In Kubuntu I had bluedevil which set everything up, on here I'm not sure where to go from here. Any suggestions please? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're running Arch you'll want to install bluez and bluez-utils. Both are available from the official repositories. So just execute:

`sudo pacman -S bluez bluez-utils`

Then start the bluetooth service with:

`sudo systemctl start bluetooth`

And if you'd also like bluetooth to start at boot:

`sudo systemctl enable bluetooth`

Follow the full instructions on the Arch wiki [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth#Installation). For help using the `bluetoothctl` command.

Comment: For whatever reason, immediately after my keyboard got paired, it gets disconnected, but I managed to solve the problem simply by connecting to it using `connect my:keyboard:mac`. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

If you can't see any devices listed you may install the 'bluez-hid2hci' driver that it worked for mine.